# Table-layout:fixed rendering differences in Safari

Tags: html, cross-browser, rendering

Basically the problem I have is that in Safari/Chrome it is changing the width of my columns even though I have specified a) a width on the table, b) table-layout:fixed, and c) specific widths on my first row that when added with the padding and border values add up to the width of the table specified. In IE7 and Firefox 3 the table is rendered the same. But in Safari/Chrome it decides to make the second column bigger by taking space from the other columns.

Any ideas? I have a [very simple sample page](http://www.patmortech.com/testtablecolumnwidths.htm) that you can look at, as well as [an image](http://www.patmortech.com/render.gif) showing how the table is rendered in all three browsers for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around, I think that this is caused by the following webkit bugs: [13339](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13339) and [18565](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18565). Basically a problem with how it uses the border and padding values in calculating the final width of the columns.

I ended up doing some browser-sniffing and setting some different css values based on that for webkit browsers so that the final rendering was the same as FF and IE.

Answer (score 6):

In buggy webkits, `table-layout: fixed` also gives your table cells `box-sizing: border-box`.  One alternative to browser detection is explicitly set `box-sizing: border-box` to get consistent behavior across browsers, then adjust your widths and heights accordingly (widths and heights must be increased to include padding and borders).

```
#my-table td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get around this problem by removing the padding from the `<th>` with the fixed width. You can then safely add padding to the `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading some Reset CSS? 
http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/

Answer (score 0):

I made a Kendo grid have table:fixed-width. All the columns disappeared but only in Safari. Upon inspection, the td elements all have a computed style width of -3px. If I remove table:fixed-width, it's fine. If I specify custom pixel widths (but not percentages), it's fine. If I disable every style applied from every css source I can find (in the console style tab), the problem is not fixed it and nothing there sets width -3px.

So I have to either set all the column pixel widths or else not use table:fixed-width.