# chrome vs FF/IE/Opera in calculating table cell width ? (table-layout:fixed)

Tags: google-chrome, padding, column-width

I've searched now for almost half a day... but I couldn't find out why chrome6/7 seems to be the only browser in comparison to IE8/FF3.6/Opera that does not add the padding to the specified width of an table cell.

Of course this becomes crucial if you're working with table-layout:fixed, 
due to the fact that all of a sudden they have to pay attention to the specified px widths.

**Okay finally my question:** does anyone know why Chrome calculates differently, and which browser is right (standard conform), and hopefully, is there an elegant solution?

At the moment, my only solution would be a conditional comment with a chrome.css where I add the padding to the width manually ... shiver...

*(btw: anyone who feels tempted to tell that px widths are not proper webdeveloping... feel free to leave this page silently)*

**ADDITION:** (*in respect to the replys*)
first of all thank you for your immediate replys... i was trying to make it as short as possible, and there for i reduced the facts to the minimum... but, as you mentioned, there are a lots of varibales in webdeveloping and so i try to clarify...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4 /strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div { width:300px; }
        table { table-layout:fixed; width:100%; height:50px; }
        td.col1 { width:20px; background-color:blue; }
        td.col2 { width:40px; background-color:red; }
        td.col3 { width:60px; background-color:yellow; }
        td.col3 { width:auto; background-color:yellow; } 

        td { padding:5px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"></td>
                <td class="col2"></td>
                <td class="col3"></td>
                <td class="col4"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

now if you toggle the css line

```
td { padding:5px; }
```

in different browsers, you'll see that chrome includes the padding, within the width, while the others add it

hope thats helps to clarify and thanks in advance
berny

Comment: Could you post a brief example that demonstrates the problem that you're seeing?

Comment: Are you supplying a valid doctype? e.g. rendering in standards mode. this makes a significant difference when trying to control rendering.

Comment: i added few lines to my original post, hope that helps to clarify

Comment: Just noticed that in your edited example above, you have two td.col3's in your style sheet.  As this would be forehead-flattening if this were your issue, I can only assume it's a minor typo in the post, and not your actual code.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and, unfortunately, I didn't find a real solution, but I found two other threads, a bug report + a work around.

Threads:

1. [Table-layout:fixed rendering differences in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943369/table-layoutfixed-rendering-differences-in-safari)
2. [Webkit browsers not accounting for padding when determining cell width in table-layout:fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442173/webkit-browsers-not-accounting-for-padding-when-determining-cell-width-in-table-l)

Bug report:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13339

Possible solution: see second thread.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried reproducing your problem, but the following looks exactly the same to me in Chrome 7 and Firefox 3.6:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
table { table-layout: fixed; border: 1px solid black; }
td { width: 5px; background: green; outline: 1px solid red; padding: 5px; }
</style>
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

To solve your problem, I would recommend you first try adding a doctype if you don't already have one. Using a doctype will trigger standards mode, which mean that behavior is more likely to be consistent between browsers. The one I use above, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, is the HTML5 doctype, but it actually works to trigger standards mode in [pretty much all browsers](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).

If standards mode doesn't help you get better consistency, then try reducing your problem down to a minimal example; strip away everything extraneous, until you are left with only enough to see your problem. The example I gave above shows how minimal I mean; just enough markup and styling to be able to easily see the tables and compare them between browsers. Once you reduce to a minimal example, you may see the problem yourself, or if not, you will have something that you can post on a forum like StackOverflow and get much more useful answers, as people don't have to guess as to what your problem is, or wade through a whole page worth of HTML and CSS just to find the one little issue you were mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

For table-layout:fixed with CSS:

```
td { width: 150px; padding: 5px; }
```

Below shows the result (Left: Chrome; Right: Firefox):
[stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post image.. yet]

CHROME: 5-140-5
FIREFOX: 5-150-5

Suggestion/Workaround:
try not to use padding on the td layer. Wrap your content within td with a div/span element:

```
span.column_wrap
{
    padding: 0 3px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 26px;
}

<td><span class="column_wrap">content here</span></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably one of the two:

1. You have set the width attribute of the table and of the individual cells, and the total widths of the cells is not the same as the value you assigned to the table; or
2. The total width of the cells (and thus the width of the table) is larger than the width of the containing element (div). If this is the case the Chrome will redistribute the cell widths making them differ from your CSS.

Looking at your markup I'd suggest you start by first setting an actual value to td.col3 or remove 'auto' and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

After having this bug as well I noticed that in Chrome, if you add the height of table row(for example your table's title) to 40, then add 5 padding to the whole table, the table row height now becomes 45. This doesn't happen on Firefox.

So, in order to fix this, I set the height of that row in css and added 0 padding:

```css
.title {
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0px; 
}
```

On the table row that includes the table title, then add padding to the table.
Now I can have 45px height + 10px padding with the title row staying to 45px(instead of becoming 55).