# Doctype or padding - Chrome doesn't display the table like FF, IE, Opera

Tags: google-chrome, padding, doctype, column-width

My problem looks similar to the question I have found here:

[chrome vs FF/IE/Opera in calculating table cell width ? (table-layout:fixed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605367/chrome-vs-ff-ie-opera-in-calculating-table-cell-width-table-layoutfixed)

I simplified the page. The page contains a table, that looks the same in all browsers, but Chrome. I beleive the problem is padding (don't know how to fix it) or doctype (I don't know too much about doctype)... Please help me make Chrome view the same as in any other browser. Thank you.
Below is my html-page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>

<title>Looks different in Chrome vs FF, IE, Opera</title>

<style>


table.maintable {
    background-color:yellow;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
    word-wrap:break-word;

}

table.maintable th, table.maintable td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin:0;
    padding:14px;
}


</style>

</head>


<body>
I want the date look like 05/10/2011, in 1 string. Chrome cuts the date into 2 parts. All other browsers are OK.  The problem is style <u>padding:14px;</u>, but we need some padding in cells. <br>
Also <b>table-layout:fixed;</b> and <b>word-wrap:break-word;</b> are needed because any long text without any spaces will not destroy the table size in this case. How to make Chrome look like any other browser?
<table class="maintable" style="width:510px;"><tbody>
<tr><th style="width:57px;">number number</th><th style="width:75px;">date</th><th>current info</th><th style="width:90px;">more</th></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://google.com">40</a></td>
    <td>05/10/2011</td>
    <td><a href="http://google.com">2 lines in Crhome but 3 lines in other browsers. Also check the date.</a></td>
    <td><a href="http://google.com">more...</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>   

</body></html>
```

If you believe my first string (doctype declaration) is wrong, please show me a proper one. The web-site in one of Cyrillic languages. No xml is used.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the padding is causing the date to wrap due to available space.
You could try to put a span tag around the dates with a .no-wrap class and give the class the property white-space: nowrap to prevent dates from wrapping.

```
.no-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
...
<td>
    <span class="no-wrap">01/11/2014</span>
</td>
...
```